# What happens in git push -u my_url master

Tags: git

I have a repository created with git init and some commits.

Having forgotten the proper sequence of first doing `git remote add origin my_git_url`, I just did `git push -u my_git_url master`

The push was successful and it shows `Branch master set up to track remote branch master from my_git_url.`

So what is the state of my current repo?  I know that `origin` is unset, so is it tracking an anonymous remote with no name and just the url?

Comment: You can probably take a look at `.git/config` to know what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Piotr Skotnicki said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606405/what-happens-in-git-push-u-my-url-master#comment74263129_43606405), you can just examine your `.git/config` file to see.  However, after Git says:

> ```
> Branch master set up to track remote branch master from <url>
> ```

what you will see is:

> ```
> [branch "master"]
>         remote = <url>
>         merge = refs/heads/master
> ```

In other words, instead of remembering the other Git's branch via a *named* remote (which gets you all those other good benefits like remote-tracking branches and not having to type in long URLs), your Git is now remembering an upstream by an *anonymous* remote.  Both `git fetch` and `git pull` (which just runs `git fetch` anyway) will contact whatever Git answers at the URL, just as they would if you used a named remote and made them follow that to the remote's URL setting.  The second command that `git pull` runs will use the traces left in `FETCH_HEAD` (in fact, `git pull` forces this whether or not you switch to using a named remote).

Just set up a named remote, run `git fetch` to populate the remote-tracking branches, and then either `git push -u` again or use `git branch --set-upstream-to` (as in [Jai Kumar Rajput's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43606586/1256452)), to fix the `branch.master.remote` setting, to get the remote-tracking branch benefit back.

Comment: So using an anonymous remote, I cannot get a remote-tracking branch?  It would seem to me that the only difference is that instead of my `master` tracking `origin/master`, it is now tracking `my_git_url/master`, which seems the same?  (gitk does fail to show the tracked remote branch which seems to suggest otherwise...)

Comment: @Woofas: you're mixing up the idea of "tracking a branch" with the idea of a "remote-tracking branch". Git lets one branch *track* another, but has a completely separate thing called a *remote-tracking branch*. To make it even more confusing, a "remote-tracking branch" is local, not remote; doesn't track another branch at all; and is not even a branch! :-) Still, that's the name Git gives it. Anyway, a *remote-tracking branch* like `origin/master` can only be created when using a named remote like `origin`, never when using a URL. Running `git fetch` creates and updates them, based [cont'd]

Comment: ... based on the contents of `remote.<name>.fetch` in your `.git/config`. For this to work, the remote has to have a `[remote "<name>"]` section in there, with a `fetch` line (one or more, really). If you look at a typical `.git/config` you will see `[remote "origin"]` has `url = ...` and then `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. It's that last line that makes `git fetch` create and update `origin/master` and the like.

Comment: If you wanted a better name for "remote-tracking branch", we could perhaps call it "locally-cached memory of branch found on foreign Git the last time we talked with that Git and decided to update the local memory", but that's kind of unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

Side-effect of pushing with the -u option like mention here

```
 git push -u origin master
```

The equivalent long option is `--set-upstream`

`git branch --set-upstream` is deprecated and may be removed in a relatively distant future.

`git branch [-u|--set-upstream-to]` has been introduced with a saner order of arguments.

If you want to  make an existing branch track a remote branch,

```
git branch -u upstream/foo
```